# 休んだほうがいい仕事ができます translation

Tags: translation

長い時間働き続けるより、少し休んだほうがいい仕事ができますよ。 I'm not sure about translation of this.
In my opinion, I think it is " I got a job that I should rest a bit than to continue working for a long time" but I think mine is not correct and sounds a bit confusing.

Actually I don't know how to translate"長い時間働き続けるより、少し休んだほうがいい仕事" properly. I can only translate as "A job that (I) should rest a bit than to continue working for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not [少し休んだほうがいい]仕事ができます, it's 少し休んだほうが、いい仕事ができます.

> 長い時間働き続けるより、少し休んだほうがいい仕事ができます。
>   Instead of working for a long time straight, resting for a bit will make you work better.